# Struggling pineapple plant

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-care

I have a plant pineapple that I started with the crown of another pineapple. I've had it for a few years, but for quite a few reasons, all of the leaves got ripped off, or rotted (too much moisture got locked in with the extra supports I had to give it).  So now my plant has no leaves. Is there any chance of it growing more? or living again??